# Conditional Expectation in Bivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BUTV.jpg)

I solved it  using the correct formula & got this answer but it shows that this is incorrect answer.
What did I do wrong ?
Thank You in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which is the correct answer? Your forumla looks correct to me,  but an approximation you did

I find

$$\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_2=-0.2]=2-\frac{4.8}{36}(-0.2+2)=2-\frac{48}{360}\cdot\frac{18}{10}=\frac{44}{25}=1.76$$

Comment: I was approximating the values to 4 decimal places that might be the reason & 1.76 is the correct answer. Thank You for helping out.